# Убрать автоматическое установление background-color для текста в Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Текст который добавляется по клику на кнопку имеет свой `background-color`. После удаления этого текста если начать печатать текст то `background-color` сохраняется. Это репродюсится только на Хроме. Причем можно заметить что `span` не тот который был добавлен при добавлении текста.
Шаги чтобы воспроизвести проблему:

1. вставили текст нажав на кнопку "Add Text";
2. удаляем текст
3. печатаем новый текст

Как сделать так чтобы после удаления текста не появлялся `background-color` у текста который мы сами печатаем.

```js
function onAddText() {
  const html = this.generateHtml('Text');
  textArea.focus();
  document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, html);
}
function onBold() {
  document.execCommand('bold');
  textArea.focus();
}

function generateHtml(value) {
  return `<span id="text">${value}</span>&#8203`;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown',($event) => {
    document.execCommand('removeFormat', false, null);
  });
```

```css
#textArea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#text {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div contenteditable="true" id="textArea"></div>
    <button onclick="onAddText()">Add Text</button>
    <button onclick="onBold()">Bold</button>
    <script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: На javascript проверять, если у span нет текста - удалять у него класс text.

Comment: если внимательно посмотреть, то span не содержит класс text. Но спасибо за ответ;)

Comment: И тут return `<span class="text">${value}</span>&#8203`; - не содержит?

Comment: Не пойму Вас. Если проинспектировать элемент в дев тулзах, то вы увидете что после того как будет удален текст, то span отсутствует в DOM. А после того когда начинаем печатать текст появлеется span без класса text и с инлан установленным стилем.

Comment: Виноват. Был неправ. Span - инлайновый элемент и когда вы добавляете его через execCommand( ), то у инлайновых элементов, что будут потом, остаются те же стили. Если в диве нет текстов и спанов, в момент, когда они удалены из DOM, можно воспользоваться document.execCommand('removeFormat', false, null); это должно сбрасывать стили именно для инлайновых элементов.

Comment: Что-то мне не помогла это команда `document.execCommand('removeFormat', false, null);` (Я обновил код вместе с ней). Но вы наталкнули меня на другую мысль) Если в этом виноват инлайновый элемент, то ему можно задать `display: inline-block;` и проблема решена)

Answer (score 2):

Нашел решение проблемы в том что дал элементу `display: inline-block;` Спасибо Quazimorda что натолкнул на мысль)

Comment: Я ниже отдельным ответом привёл функцию, а использовать её можно так:  <div contenteditable="true" id="textArea" onkeyup="foo();"></div>

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, костыль ли это или валидное решение, но к диву с id="textArea" к событию onkeyup можно привязать функцию:

```
function foo() {
  document.execCommand('removeFormat', false, null);
}
```

В этом случае, всё, что набирается в блоке с клавиатуры, будет лишено инлайновых стилей.